# printf "%c\n" call in assembly only prints a single character, not a whole string

Tags: linux, assembly, printf, att

I've a problem with using `printf` in assembly. Here is a piece of  code

```
push $buff
push $end_str
call printf
add $8, %esp
```

The `o_buff` is a variable declared like this : `.lcomm o_buff, 32` and `end_str` is `end_str: .ascii "%c\n"` . In `o_buff` are bytes that states for ascii codes, here is a sample form gdb `x /4b 0x0804a028` example: `0x0804a028 <o_buff> 49 48 49 48` which suppose to state for `1010` , but instead **i always get `(` no matter what will be inside of `o_buff` variable.**

I save register on the stack before calling `printf` and after i pop them. When i just move one byte : `movb (%eax,%esi,1), %dl` and then `push %edx` (of course before i xor edx register) i get a proper output, but this is just one char.

Can someone point me where i have made mistake? I'm using GAS AT&T syntax

Comment: `%c` is the printf format specifier for a single character - maybe you want `%s` ?

Comment: owww, my. So dumb of my thanks:)